# MMR dropped in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends I am Gold 5 or 4 (depending on when you will read this). My MMR was really high since I had more than double of wins compared to my losses. This made me play against high gold and low plat players.
However, I was on a losing streak and I started playing duo queue with a friend that is Silver 5.
This drastically dropped my MMR. If I want to raise my MMR again, does it help to just duo queue with a friend which has higher MMR than me (let's say high plat), or is winning solo queue the only solution here?

Comment: MMR is kind of tricky when playing with friends, because it takes your party into consideration. I'm not sure about how fast it goes up when duo queuing with higher MMR players, but you'll definitely play higher ranked players.

Comment: Yes that's true. I sure hope I get my MR fixed soon again so I gain 30 points and only lose 13 points again :).

Comment: This is the entire point of MMR - over time, it finds the 'right' place in the ladder for you, and you then climb or fall down the ladder as you improve or are overtaken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  If you duo with a higher friend, it won't really make a huge change to your MMR since your combined MMR will place you vs in equally skilled matchup as a team.

The only thing that will raise your MMR is simply playing games and winning more than you lose regardless if you go solo or duo.

Comment: +1, many people think they will get more/less lp, if they play with higher/lower ranked player. But that's not true

Comment: What if you're bronze 5 and you duo with your diamond 1 friend? I believe your MMR can significantly increase (if you win) at a rate higher than normal

Comment: You can only duo queue with someone that is within 1 tier of your own ranking. Silver can duo with bronze and gold, diamond can duo with platinum and master/challenger. Even if a bronze and a diamond could duo, it would find another team with a similar average ranking, so your MMR will still rise/drop at the same rate.

Answer (score 1):

Duoing can help if the player you're playing with is dramatically higher in rank, otherwise it wouldn't work for [elo boosters](https://lolboost.net/DuoQueue.aspx). If you're close in MMR, it shouldn't matter too much to your MMR. I think it's more likely that you and your friend had a bit of a bad streak.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not Duoing unless its for fun basis. You get put against a higher MMR team and the players outside your duo are more likely to lose their lanes which in turn makes it harder for you to win. Plus your pick order is pretty bad anyways.